# HTML select from list

Tags: html

I'm a HTML noob, but what is the easiest way to create something like

[image]

Where I have the possibility to make a slection from a bigger list

Comment: I tried with <select and multiple="yes" > where I can select more then one item through the ctrl button but I lost it when I want to fill in right list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `<select multiple>` and event handlers.

You'll need two of those, and some buttons/links to move the selection from one to another.

You'll need to attach event handlers for those buttons to move the selected `<options>` from one `<select>` to the other by means of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner in HTML then you might want to start and the beginning.
I don't know what your goal is so i can't adjust my answer to it. The element you are looking for is called SELECT

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php

And if you really like to make it like the availible selection menu you sould take a look into jQuery as well. Though from the fact that you are a beginner in HTML that would be kind of hard.